# Google Chrome background tabs don't load/build until selected in 2023

Tags: windows-10, browser-tabs

Trying to get Chrome to load pages when I "open link in new tab"
Win10 64bit
Version 109.0.5414.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.